# Activiti - how to set condition for exclusive gateway in Java

Tags: java, activiti

I have an exclusive gateway in Activiti, how I can set the condition variable in Java code for exclusive gateway?

```
variableData.put("condition", conditionVar);
taskService.complete(task.getId(), variableData);
```

How I can extract task variable on gateway flow? Is it possible or I have to use process variable?

Comment: Can you better describe exactly what you need?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you design your workflow with conditional exclusive gateway then it will generate XML like below,

```
<exclusiveGateway id="exclusiveGw" name="Exclusive Gateway" />

<sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="exclusiveGw" targetRef="theTask1">
  <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression">${input == 1}</conditionExpression>
</sequenceFlow>
```

so you need to provide a value of `'input'` variable as

`variableData.put("input", 1);`

If your task is `ServiceTask` then you can do like below

```
delegateExecution.setVariable("input",1);
```

For more help http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnExclusiveGateway

Comment: Nice answer! Helped :)

Answer (score 1):

**In process deploy time:**

- you can add expression condition in Java by extends `org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.parser.factory.DefaultActivityBehaviorFactory` and inject to `ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl`

**In process execution time:**

- you can add process variables as variable of you defined expression. It could be result of your condition in Java: `${result == true}`

  `variableData.put("result", resultOfJavaCondition);
  taskService.complete(task.getId(), variableData);`

Answer (score 0):

> How I can extract task variable on gateway flow? Is it possible or I have to use process variable?

You cant. You need to retrieve the value from task variable and copy into process variable. After which you can use it decide the flow.

Variables in workflows exist at two levels; the process execution level and the task level. If you set the value of a variable in a task, the new value is not available at the process level. If you want to use a variable across tasks, or between a task and conditional flow, you need to copy the variable to the process execution level. Process level variables are available to tasks and sequence flows.

https://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/wf-process-def-variables.html